# Certificate file or key file is missing, falling back to non-SSL mode: Heroku

Tags: heroku, meanjs, heroku-toolbelt

I am trying to deploy my meanjs 0.4 app to Heroku. I have gone through all the [procedure](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git). The app is deployed but when I go to the url (*myapp.herokuapp.com)*, i just see a blank page.
When i run "heroku logs" command, from the logs, the rest seems ok apart from the following error;

```
.....
2015-10-02T10:13:50.332401+00:00 app[web.1]: + Error: Certificate file or key file is missing, falling back to non-SSL mode

2015-10-02T10:13:50.337817+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-10-02T10:13:50.183794+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-10-02T10:13:50.332567+00:00 app[web.1]:   To create them, simply run the following from your shell: sh ./scripts/generate-ssl-certs.sh
......
```

I have run sh ./scripts/generate-ssl-certs.sh several times and nothing changes. I have [uninstalled heroku toolbelt](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-command#uninstalling-the-heroku-cli) and re-installed it but the problem persists., How can I get over this error?

Previously, I also tried [deploying an already existing git repo](http://www.tilcode.com/deploying-a-mean-stack-app-to-heroku/) (of the same app) to heroku, and the same problem persisted.

I am willing to provide more information if the question is not clear enough.

Comment: Are you running the app in production mode ?